Image width not respected when converting HTML to PDF
I am having problems with converting html to pdf with weasyprint (python).
It seems like it is not adhering to "width" in the img tag:
<img src="..." alt="Logo" width="300" />

No matter what I try here, it takes up 100% of the width of the page in the pdf output.
However, it works when looking at the html code through a browser.
I have tried

Putting the  tag inside a table with width specified on column level
Putting the  tag inside  tag with CSS to define with of the columns:

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60% 40%; 

I have created a html file here which illustrates the problem: https://gist.github.com/tobiasgardner/be6e9efba80f13e6aa6464cbcf8613ad
And the output (pdf) looks like this:


Did you also try to add an height?
